# SQL avoid 0 in the calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can anyone help me try to solve this equation? The "Lost_Weight" is a calculation field and I'm trying to get the result of HWeight - renWeight = '0' if the renWeight is 0. The where clause has a controversial statement that put a Challenge to me to make that happen. See below.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Name.ID,
                        dbo.Name.CO_ID, 
                        dbo.Name.FULL_NAME, 
                        dbo.Name.STATE_PROVINCE, dbo.Tops_Profile.START_WGHT, 
                        dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT, 
                        dbo.Tops_Profile.H_WEIGHT - dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT AS Lost_Weight, 
                        dbo.Tops_Profile.H_WEIGHT, 
                        dbo.Name.JOIN_DATE,
                        dbo.Name.BIRTH_DATE, 
                        RIGHT(dbo.TOPS_AWARDS.AWARD_TYPE, 15) AS AWARDS_TYPE, 
                        dbo.TOPS_AWARDS.AWARD_CATEGORY, 
                       dbo.TOPS_AWARDS.AWARD_DATE, 
                       dbo.vw_RegDirs.TARGET_ID AS 
                        RD_ID,
                       dbo.vw_Coords.TARGET_ID AS Coord_ID, 
                       dbo.vw_Coords.FULL_NAME AS 
                      Coord_Name, 
                      dbo.vw_AreaCapts.TARGET_ID AS AC_ID, dbo.Name.STATUS
FROM            dbo.Name INNER JOIN  dbo.Tops_Profile 
   ON dbo.Name.ID = dbo.Tops_Profile.ID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.vw_RegDirs 
                        ON dbo.Name.CO_ID = dbo.vw_RegDirs.CHAPTER
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_Coords 
                    ON dbo.Name.CO_ID = dbo.vw_Coords.CHAPTER 
INNER JOIN  dbo.vw_AreaCapts 
      ON dbo.Name.CO_ID = dbo.vw_AreaCapts.CHAPTER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.TOPS_AWARDS 
    ON dbo.Name.ID = dbo.TOPS_AWARDS.ID
WHERE        (dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT <> '0')
            AND (dbo.Name.STATUS = 'a') 
       AND (dbo.Tops_Profile.H_WEIGHT - dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT >= 100') 
   OR (dbo.Name.STATUS = 'a') AND (dbo.TOPS_AWARDS.AWARD_TYPE LIKE '%Century%')
```

right now if the renewal_weight is 0 it automatically give me the number from the H_WEIGHT in the Lost_Weight field and I need the result to be 0 if the RENEWAL_WEIGHT is 0.

Comment: Please give whole SQL statement. Also, give the schema of table to understand the background

Comment: Why are you comparing calculations to text? What are the data types of `H_Weight` and `Renewal_Weight`?

Comment: numbers. data type is 'float'

Comment: @Venkataraman R i uploaded the whole sql statment.

Comment: You can and should change your outer join to an inner join - because that is really what your query requires. And you can safely (and forever) stop using "top 100 percent" since that does nothing useful. And you only confuse things by abbreviating actual column names or misspelling them. And I'll guess that you need to properly add parentheses to your where clause to use the correct OR logic.

Comment: @SMor all this has been added to the query when I moved it to be view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing 0 is a special value in this situation. This can be fixed by using CASE

Replace

```
dbo.Tops_Profile.H_WEIGHT - dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT AS Lost_Weight
```

With

```
CASE WHEN  RENEWAL_WEIGHT = 0 THEN 0 
     ELSE dbo.Tops_Profile.H_WEIGHT - dbo.Tops_Profile.RENEWAL_WEIGHT
END  AS Lost_Weight
```